# Android : Representing graphics in a smooth manner

Tags: android, graphics, visualization, magnetometer

I am developing an indoor positioning app. One of the features of the map is representing the collected magnetic field strength data in a view.

It is represented in the following manner:

1. The data is collected at every 1m point along x & y (see first picture with data visualisation off)
2. The magnetic field strength value is proportional to the hue of the colour displayed
3. At each point a circle is drawn with the colour defined in (2)

[image]
[image]

My question is - how do I represent the graphic in a smooth manner, in the second picture, you can clearly see the circular outline. Is there a way to blend the overlapping images and display something similar to the third picture.

[image]

Comment: seems you have to "blur" your map

Comment: works like a charm! Sorry for the noob question, I'm new to android app dev.